# How to select a div id in firebug command?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, firebug

I have a html defined like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
...
</head>    
<body>
<div id="nav">
    <a href="/">home</a> |
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}      
        <a href="/save/">submit</a> | <a href="/user/{{ user.username}}/"{{ user.username }}</a> | <a href="/logout/">logout</a>
    {% else %}
          <a href="/login">login</a> | <a href="/register/">register</a>    
    {% endif %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firebug Console I type the following to hide the nav class:

```
$("#nav").hide()
```

But when I run it I get this error message:

```
TypeError: $("#nav") is null

$("#nav").hide()     with(_...e() }; (line 2)
```

nav is clearly there, I can even see it in the HTML tab of Firebug, what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: first , `nav` is id not a class. and second you are not showing how you connect jquery. what you get when you do just `$` in console?

Comment: Are you able to select other elements? for example: $('a')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're missing jQuery**

Add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Between the `<head></head>` tags.

Comment: Wouldn't he get `$ is undefined` in that case?

Comment: I just tested it locally and running `$(whatever)` results in `'TypeError: $(whatever) is null`.

Comment: +1 you're right! he must be missing jQuery. If not, something overwrote `$`, but I doubt that's the case here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not loaded any library such as jQuery and are using the Firefox version  of `$` which is defined as a shortcut for `document.getElementById`

Remove the `#` from the id and it should give you the DOM node as expected.
Or load a library as jQuery :)

Comment: `$` is in fact a shortcut to `document.getElementById` but of Firebug, not Firefox.

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#.24.28id.29